# Cucumber with and without Rest - Assured. What are the advantages?

Tags: cucumber, rest-api, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

Currently my team uses Cucumber as a testing framework.

We need to start testing REST web services. I understood that REST-Assured is one of the leading tools for that.

1. Can these tools be used in coordination? An example or a link would
   be great.
2. If yes, what are the advantages of using Rest-Assured
   together with Cucumber?
3. Also I've heard about Serenity. What are its
       advantages over Cucumber, if any, and is it recommended to use?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to understand why I was downvoted here

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I would guess that because your point 3 makes your question too broad for a single question. Asking if Rest-Assured can be used with Cucumber and if so what advantages does that bring makes a good question. Questions you have about Cucumber vs Serenity should probably be a separate question.

Comment: Thank you Kate. It maybe that you are right, but maybe not. To avoid unnecessary anger, it would have been better if downvoting was enforcing an explanation of the reason.

Comment: @dushkin In my experience, it's better to just not let it get to you =)

Comment: This is so true!!! https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Sure.

Cucumber is a test runner. The goal of this kind of tool is only to execute a suite with certain structure is a certain way.

Cucumber manages the execution of certain methods according to the matches of *.feature* files.

Rest-assure is a library. It abstracts HTTP calls.

You can add anything under Cucumber step definition methods, including statements with Rest Assured.

More details [here](http://angiejones.tech/rest-assured-with-cucumber-using-bdd-for-web-services-automation/).

2 - You will be able to abstract HTTP calls due Rest Assured and define scenarios in a BDD fashion.

3 - Mostly opinion-based; both have a similar learning-curve and features.